# Export the searched result to .CSV, PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I'm still beginner in PHP MySQL. I'm looking for the most efficient / easiest way for **`exporting`** the **`Searched Data`** to **`.CSV`**.

**Scenario:** 
I would like to have export button where the result of the search  can be export to `.CSV` like.

Maybe the process something like this:

> Search any data you want > ( Click Search Button ) 
>  
>   if no result found > prompt error > die 
>   if any record found > Display > ( Click Export Button ) > Export to .CSV

**Here is my code of my search form:**

```
  <?php
  session_start();
  include_once "dbconnect.php";
  date_default_timezone_set('Hongkong');


  //LOG IN VALIDATION
  if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
  {
  header("Location: index.php");
  }
  $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user']);
  $userRow=mysql_fetch_array($res);   

  ?>

  //HTML SEARCH FORM IS HERE
    //SEARCH BUTTON <br/><h5 style="float:right;"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-theme02" name="search" ><i class="fa fa-check">Search Customers</i></button></h5>

  //BUTTON FOR IMPORTING THE SEARCHED DATA INTO CSV
  //DONT HAVE FUNCTION YET DON'T KNOW HOW TO EXPORT THE DATA 
  <button type="submit" name="EXPORT">EXPORT TO CSV</button>


 <?php
 $number = 1;//NOT IMPORTANT, JUST USE TO NUMBERING THE ITEMS SEARCHED

 //TABLE 
 echo "<table class=\"table table-hover\" id=\"table1\" >";
          //TABLE ROW NAMES - SQL TABLE 
            echo " <hr><thead><tr>";
          echo "<th></th>";
            echo "<th>Globe Number</th>";
          echo "<th>Full Name</th>";
          echo "<th>State</th>";
          echo "<th>Country</th>";
          echo "<th>Virtual Number</th>";
          echo "<th>Date of Subscription</th>";
          echo "<th>Expiration Date</th>"; 
          echo "<th></th>";
          echo "</tr></thead>";       

          //FUNCTION OF SEARCH BUTTON 
          if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
          $globe = htmlentities(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['globe']));
          $name = htmlentities(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']));
          $vr = htmlentities(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['virtual']));
          $ctry= htmlentities(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['country']));


          if (empty($globe) && empty($name) && empty($vr) && empty($ctry) && empty($dateStarted)  && empty($dateExpired) 
            && empty($time) && empty($transaction) && empty($subs) && empty($status) && empty($remarks) && empty($year) && empty($month)) {
          echo '<script>alert(\'Select atleast 1 filter\')</script>'; 
          exit;        
         }

          //SEARCH CONDITIONS
          if (!empty($globe)) {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM `subscribers` WHERE `globeNumber` =  '".$globe."' AND `agentCode`='".$agent."' ORDER BY `dateStarted` DESC ";

          }if (!empty($name)) {
           $sql = "SELECT * FROM `subscribers` WHERE  `fName` LIKE  '%".$name."%' OR `lName` LIKE  '%".$name."%'  AND `agentCode`='".$agent."' ORDER BY `dateStarted` DESC ";

          }if (!empty($vr)){
           $sql = "SELECT * FROM `subscribers` WHERE `virtualNumber` =  '".$vr."' AND `agentCode`='".$agent."' ORDER BY `dateStarted` DESC ";

          }if (!empty($ctry)){
           $sql = "SELECT * FROM `subscribers` WHERE `country` = '".$ctry."' AND `agentCode`='".$agent."' ORDER BY `dateStarted` DESC  ";


          //COMBINATION CONDITIONS
          // I MINIMIZE THE CONDITION FOR SEARCH HERE            
         } if (!empty($globe) && !empty($name)) {

          $sql = "SELECT * FROM `subscribers` WHERE `globeNumber` =  '".$globe."' AND `fName` = '".$name."' AND `lName` = '".$name."'   
           AND `agentCode`='".$agent."' ORDER BY `dateStarted` DESC ";

        } if (!empty($globe) && !empty($vr)) {

          $sql = "SELECT * FROM `subscribers` WHERE `globeNumber` =  '".$globe."' AND `virtualNumber` = '".$vr."'
           AND `agentCode`='".$agent."' ORDER BY `dateStarted` DESC ";

        } if (!empty($globe) && !empty($ctry)) {

          $sql = "SELECT * FROM `subscribers` WHERE `globeNumber` =  '".$globe."' AND `country` = '".$ctry."'
           AND `agentCode`='".$agent."' ORDER BY `dateStarted` DESC ";
      }

        //THE QUERY RUN HERE
        if ($result=mysql_query($sql)) {
            $query_num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

              //IF NO RECORD FOUND RUN THIS
               if($query_num_rows == 0){ 
                  echo "<script> alert('No Records Found, Please try again!')</script>"; 

        } else {

         while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

          echo "<tbody><tr>";
          echo "<td>".$number."</td>";
          echo "<td>".$row['globeNumber']."</td>";
          echo "<td>".$row['lName'].", ".$row['fName']." ".$row['mName']."</td>";
          echo "<td>".$row['state']."</td>";
          echo "<td>".$row['country']."</td>";
          echo "<td>".$row['virtualNumber']."</td>";
          echo "<td>".$row['dateStarted']."</td>";
          echo "<td>".$row['dateExpired']."</td>";
          ++$number;//NOT IMPORTANT, JUST USE FOR NUMBERING THE ITEMS SEARCHED

          echo "</form></tr>";
          echo "string";
  }}}} ?>
```

**PS:** I'm still using MySQL because I want to familiarize first with this.

Comment: @Drew: yes I reported it for deletion sir. Still broad sir?  My question here is `How can I Export to csv  the result from search form?`

Comment: I asked you to at least show some sample output you want, and steer toward mysql first. Instead of improving the question with such output (saying all you see is PHP code showing up), and that no other refs on the Stack worked, well you know the rest

Comment: @Drew: I see sir I will edit this soon. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Bellow steps will help you.

> 1. Create a function for retrieve the records for search result
> 2. Validate the inputs and call this function and return the values in the form of array/object
> 3. If result is empty then return false
> 4. Display the fetched records
> 5. If "Clicked Export" submit same values of search with one export flag
> 6. Check for flag you set and call same function for search
> 7. Set header for download CSV file
> 8. Print the result with a separator like '|' or ','

Comment: Could you please provide a working example of this implementation? Thanks.